# invalid floating point argument when reading from CSV

Tags: bash, syntax, sequence, carriage-return

I'm looping over a CSV:

```
Joe,12,23
Steve,45,87
Karen,34,142

CSV=data.csv

while IFS=',' read name foo bar
do
    for i in $(seq $foo $bar);
    do
        #things
    done;
done < $CSV
```

...but for some reason, `seq` is trying to divide the last number line ending `\r`

Comment: You don't separate the variables in `read` with comma, you separate them with spaces: `read name foo bar`

Comment: @Barmar sorry typed it wrong in the example. Edited.

Comment: Your CSV file has CRLF line endings. Fix it with `dos2unix`

Comment: Don't type your code into the question. Copy and paste your actual code, so that you don't introduce new errors and waste people's time.

Comment: fwiw, probably would've been a bit more obvious had the actual error message been included in the post, namely: `seq: invalid floating point argument: ‘23\r’` ... the `\r` would have stood out more (than the `\r` at the end of your question)

Comment: You can get `read` to trim the carriage return with `while IFS=$',\r' read ...`